# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998 when running heroku logs --tail

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku, however, i am running into some problems that i don't understand. I searched for similar problems but to no success. I ran heroku open but it only displays application error.

[image]The error below is after committing then typing heroku logs --tail

```
2022-10-27T15:29:24.523556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-27T15:29:24.587530+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-27T15:59:56.758114+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vaulteer.herokuapp.com request_id=1cc5af25-d8cc-4fc0-a8db-562612eba0e1 fwd="49.145.42.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-27T16:00:32.097214+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vaulteer.herokuapp.com request_id=93cf8986-eb7b-4e9f-995e-846f4f08c8c1 fwd="49.145.42.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-27T16:01:09.820661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vaulteer.herokuapp.com request_id=c94e620d-2c3c-42e1-820b-763011dd8e58 fwd="49.145.42.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-27T16:01:15.043521+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vaulteer.herokuapp.com request_id=cbe6c51b-5bc6-4898-ac5f-f5ba77bb488d fwd="49.145.42.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-27T18:07:29.924304+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-10-27T18:07:36.794181+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-10-27T18:07:38.902356+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
2022-10-27T18:07:38.915737+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-27T18:07:38.915738+00:00 app[web.1]: > password-manager@1.0.0 start
2022-10-27T18:07:38.915739+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/server.js
2022-10-27T18:07:38.915739+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984836+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984840+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984841+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984841+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984841+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './debug'
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984842+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984842+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/debug/src/node.js
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984842+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/debug/src/index.js
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984842+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984843+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984843+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984843+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express/index.js
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984844+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/server.js
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984844+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984845+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984845+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984845+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984864+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:14:28)
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984865+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984865+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984865+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984865+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984866+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) {
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984866+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984866+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984866+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/debug/src/node.js',
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984867+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/debug/src/index.js',
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984867+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js',
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984867+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js',
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984868+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js',
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984868+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/express/index.js',
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984868+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server/server.js'
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984868+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984869+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984873+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-27T18:07:38.984874+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.12.0
2022-10-27T18:07:39.125526+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-27T18:07:39.324865+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-27T19:52:09.765683+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-10-27T19:52:16.335694+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-10-27T19:52:18.194757+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
2022-10-27T19:52:18.206356+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-27T19:52:18.206357+00:00 app[web.1]: > password-manager@1.0.0 start
2022-10-27T19:52:18.206358+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/server.js
2022-10-27T19:52:18.206358+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269847+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269852+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269852+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269852+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269852+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './debug'
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269853+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269853+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/debug/src/node.js
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269853+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/debug/src/index.js
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269854+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269854+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269854+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269854+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/express/index.js
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269855+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/server.js
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269855+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269875+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269875+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269876+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269876+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:14:28)
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269876+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269876+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269877+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) {
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269878+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269878+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269878+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/debug/src/node.js',
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269879+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/debug/src/index.js',
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269879+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js',
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269879+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js',
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269880+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/express/lib/express.js',
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269880+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/express/index.js',
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269880+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server/server.js'
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269881+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269881+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269886+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-10-27T19:52:18.269886+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.12.0
2022-10-27T19:52:18.395749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-27T19:52:18.468515+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-28T01:03:27.021615+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vaulteer.herokuapp.com request_id=e8f46d28-87c5-459a-9e84-81209a3ff372 fwd="49.145.42.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-28T01:03:28.182114+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vaulteer.herokuapp.com request_id=02c2c4df-ff96-4491-ba6d-3d330c7df316 fwd="49.145.42.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-28T01:15:16.563295+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vaulteer.herokuapp.com request_id=487bf4d4-bf13-447b-8903-c497bba1920c fwd="49.145.42.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-28T01:15:17.834727+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vaulteer.herokuapp.com request_id=7efbd535-ae24-452d-b72f-863889409f4f fwd="49.145.42.80" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Honestly, i havent tried anything that much besides npm install as this is the first time ive experienced this problem.

Comment: What is `./debug`, and why are you trying to load it in production?

Comment: Im not sure what it is too. I don't remember using it in my app, yet when I tried to deploy, this is what I got.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error.
I used the `node map` command to run the file.
Even though my file was called `main.js`
But the `node map` command runs the `map.js` file
After I changed the command to `node main` everything worked.